# Extracting formula from a number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I have this sequence:

```
| Term  | Value |
|-------+-------+
| 1     | 1     |
| 2     | 4     |
| 3     | 9     |
| 4     | 16    |
| 5     | 25    |
| 6     | 36    |
| 7     | 49    |

..and so on
```

Could anyone possibly find out (in a mathematical way) that the formula behind this sequence is $x_n = n^2$

However, I wish to use more complicated formulas such as in a real enviorment

$$floor\left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{n-1}floor\left(x+300*2^\frac{x}{7} \right)}{4}\right)$$

Comment: Generally sequences are not uniquely determined by some set of elements, but there are ways to do these kind of things numerically. They are (in my understanding) complicated enough that it probably is easier to use some prebuilt software to do it. Matlab has functions for fitting values to expressions like polynomials and sums of sines and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone possibly find out (in a mathematical way) that the formula behind this sequence is $x_n=n^2$

In general, given $N$ points $(x_i, y_i)$ such that the $x_i$ are all different, there will be a unique polynomial $f$ of degree $N-1$ or less, such that $f(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i$.

Your example has seven points: $(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), \ldots, (7, 49)$.  This means that there is a unique polynomial of degree 6 *or less* that includes these points.  It turns out in this example that the polynomial turns out to be of degree 2 (namely, $f(x) = x^2$).

To find this polynomial in your example, you'd write:
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots a_6 x^6
$$
Then your seven points yield seven equations:
$$
1 = a_0 + a_1 (1) + a_2 (1)^2 + \ldots a_6 (1)^6
$$
$$
4 = a_0 + a_1 (2) + a_2 (2)^2 + \ldots a_6 (2)^6
$$
$$
\ldots
$$
$$
49 = a_0 + a_1 (7) + a_2 (7)^2 + \ldots a_6 (7)^6
$$

Solving these seven equations for the seven variables $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_6$ yields the polynomial $f$.  In your example, the solution is $a_0 = a_1 = a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = 0$, and $a_2 = 1$, so $f(x) = x^2$.

Now write $a_n = f(n)$ and you're done.

(Note: this process indicates that two points determine a line, as we already know from geometry.  Also, three points determine a parabola, four points determine a cubic, *etc*.)

Of course, if we now received a new data point, our solution might go out the window and we'd have to start over.  For example, if you expanded your example and told us that $a_8 = -100$, then suddenly our solution $a_n = n^2$ wouldn't seem so good anymore.  However, we could just start all over and find a new polynomial of degree 7, that fit our updated set of 8 data points.

If your $N$ is large, you might not want to use polynomials of degree $N-1$.  In that case, you can always just cap the degree of the polynomials at a convenient size (set the maximum degree $d$ equal to 5 or 14 or whatever you like).  Then this same process gives $N$ linear equations in $d$ variables.  If $N > d$, so that you have more equations than variables, then there probably won't be an exact solution.  However, you can try to find a solution that is "as close as possible" to solving all the equations.  This means finding a curve of dimension $d$ so that the $N$ equations are all as close to being satisfied as possible.  A common approach is the "least-squares approximation."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)

Your question didn't indicate that you were interested in finding approximate solutions, so I won't go into this further, but there is a lot more (a LOT more) information on the subject of fitting curves to data sets.

Anyway, you hinted that you had some more complicated things in mind, but I'm not sure exactly what you wanted.  However, hopefully this answer will clarify some things for you, and help you find what you're looking for!